# I have an alertDialog in which i have check boxes . I want to retain the values of the check boxes checked in by the user

Tags: android, android-studio, checkbox, android-alertdialog, android-checkbox

I want to retain the checkbox values entered by the user.
I want the selected values to be there when the alert dialog is opened again. I have the checkboxes in *alert dialog*. Once the user chooses his/her choice and then comes back, I want the checkboxes to be checked with the previous user input until the app closes. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: use global variables for your use.

Comment: Extend dialog and have the variables and use alert dialog without creating another instance on further launch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try one this

Use two Global variable one for label and other for selction.

```
        String[] days = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "thursday"};
        boolean[] checkedItems = {false, false, false, false, false};
```

then on click show dialog

```
   private void pickWeek() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Choose some days");

   // Add a checkbox list

    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(days, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i, boolean isChecked) {

                checkedItems[i]=isChecked;
            // The user checked or unchecked a box
        }
    });

    // Add OK and Cancel buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // The user clicked OK
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

    // Create and show the alert dialog
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already got an Alertdialog you could simply use the companion Object to save the value. Save the checked valu into a variable inside of the companion Object and retrieve this value when the Alertdialog is opened again